# Trouble with WCF and WAS with web site and web service in separate application pools

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

None of the members of my team has ever been able to get a particular WCF service in our solution to work on our local machines. We've inherited it in legacy code and are trying to replace it, but it's very difficult to tell what it's doing since we can't run the debugger on it and we can't even get a response from it while debugging the main site that uses it.

The main part of our application is a web site.  This particular service is hosted in a separate application pool on IIS due to some problems with using Excel interops (which this service uses) in the same app pool as the main site.

The service appears to use net.tcp for the protocol, and I have enabled the Windows Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation feature on my machine.  I have also enabled the protocol on the Default Website and the node underneath it which is the WCF service in question (is this redundant?).

I can attach the debugger to w3wp.exe processes for both the site and the service.  When the site makes the call to the service, however, an error is immediately returned and no breakpoints in the service are hit.  The error reads:

> The service 'MySvc.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during
>   compilation.  The exception message is: The type 'MyNamespace.MySvc',
>   provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive,
>   or provided in the configuration element

Note, I have obviously redacted the real service name, etc, from this post.  After attempting to follow solutions proposed on numerous similar questions, I have gotten nowhere.  I am wondering if the problem is exacerbated by the separate app pools.

Below is the Web.config from the service project.  The SVC file is named UploadAndImport.svc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- REDACTED SECTIONS PERTAINING TO LOGGING AND ENTERPRISE LIBRARY -->
    </configSections>
    <!-- REDACTED SECTIONS PERTAINING TO LOGGING AND ENTERPRISE LIBRARY -->
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
        <identity impersonate="true" />
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="ProjectName.UploadAndImport">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="ExcelServiceEndPointHTTP" contract="ProjectName.IUploadAndImport" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="ExcelServiceEndPointTCP" contract="ProjectName.IUploadAndImport" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <!-- This line ignores the error that 'An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integratd managed pipeline mode (system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true)'-->
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The directive in the SVC file looks like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="ProjectName.UploadAndImport" CodeBehind="UploadAndImport.svc.vb" %>
```

Comment: Make sure that the name used in the markup (the ServiceHost directive) matches the name used in the config file `<service>` section.   `MySVc.svc` is not the same as `MyNamespace.MySvc`.   Can you post both the markup for the .svc file (you can redact the service name) and the `<system.serviceModel>` section from the config?

Comment: Have you tired turning on [WCF tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Tim - I have edited the post to contain the Web.config and SVC directive.  Would it help at all to see the app.config of the project that consumes the service?

Comment: @PetarVučetin - I have not tried that, but I will read the article and see if I can get that working.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the only way I have found to get the WCF service to start up a w3pw.exe process is to right click the service reference in the client and click "Update Service Reference."